# Jquery/Spring: Why doesn't my autocomplete work when I try to pass in source using @ResponseBody?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp, autocomplete

My autocomplete always displays all the variables in my data source for some reason. Anyone know the problem?

My index.jsp

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#streamers").autocomplete({
            source: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getStreamerList'
        });
    });
</script>

 <div class="ui-widget">
                Streamer:
                <input id="streamers" type="text" name="streamerName" value=${fn:escapeXml(param.streamerName)}>
            </div>
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/getStreamerList"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
List<String> getStreamerList() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("TEST");
    list.add("BOB");
    return list;
}
```

TEST and BOB basically shows up on autocomplete no matter what I type, like "est"

Answer (score 0):

nvm this is intended behavior. I'm supposed to filter the results on the server side according to jquery API.

Answer (score 0):

have you put Jackson JSON in your class path use following cordinates for maven project

```
            <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```